# How to set images for all list items

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, listview

I didnt know how to set images for all list view item in same image in this tutorial link : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text if i change xml datasource in snows  into my default image it will not no appear in output blank display so i need to where did make change in coding part to set all list for one image

Answer (score 0):

In BinderDataClass remove following code:

```
String uri = "drawable/"+ weatherDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_ICON); 
int imageResource = vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier( uri, null, vi.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName()); 
Drawable image = vi.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResource); holder.tvWeatherImage.setImageDrawable(image);
```

If you want to change the image shown by default you can define it changing src property of ImageView in the list item xml file named list_row.xml

```
    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/list_image"

        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

        android:layout_width="60dip"

        android:layout_height="60dip"

        android:src="@drawable/sunny" />
```